# Node.js: почему require('socket.io').listen(5000) - unresolved function и как это исправить?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, сокеты, порты

Только начинаю знакомиться с Node.js, подскажите, почему может в таком коде:

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
```

listen не работать. IDE пишет: Unresolved function or method listen(), а при запуске console.log(io) вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь создать и запустить на nginx сокет для написания учебного чата...

может это устаревший синтаксис и так это уже не делается? у меня версия Node.js v18.12.1

Comment: node.js а у вас ошибка в файле .php Где подвох?

Comment: @SwaD да, файл php, но я внутри делаю так: <script>
    io = require('socket.io').listen(5000); 
    console.log(io);
</script> должно же работать? я понимаю, что так не делается, но мне ключевое - посмотреть, как работает...

Comment: Скрипты внутри html-кода обычно выполняет браузер. При чём тут Node.js вообще?

Comment: Ну и да, в браузерах никогда не было никакой функции require

Comment: Создайте js файл, в него впишите код из интрукции к socket.io и все получится. Вы тут теплое с мягким смешали... вот и не получается ничего